# Suppose $f$ is holomorphic except for a finite number of singularities...

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic except for a finite number of singularities and that $|z f(z)| \to 0$ as $|z| \to \infty$. Prove that there exists $M$ such that $|z^2 f(z) | \leq M$ for all $z$ with $|z| \geq M$.

The hint for this question says to consider $f(1/z)$. Following that hint, I can deduce that for some $\epsilon >0$, $g(z) := f (1/z)$ is holomorphic on $B_\epsilon (0)$, and, by the given,
$$\frac{g(z)}{z} = \frac{f(1/z)}{z} \to 0 \ \textrm{as} \ z \to 0$$
From here, I want to employ the maximum modulus principle on the function
$$h(z):= \begin{cases}
g(z)/z , \ \textrm{for} \ z \neq 0 \\
0, \ \textrm{for} \ z=0 \\
\end{cases}$$
This is holomorphic in $B_\epsilon (0)$, so that if $C := \max_{z \in \partial B_\epsilon (0)} |g(z)|$,
$$|h(z)| \leq C/\epsilon$$
Chasing back through what I've defined, this tells me essentially nothing; I get
$$|z f(z)| \leq \frac{C}{\epsilon}$$
for large $|z|$ (this is obviously already true since $|z f(z)| \to 0$). My assumption is to take $M := C/\epsilon$, but this does not seem to lead to the conclusion I am looking for. Am I overlooking something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *Hint.* If a function $h$ is holomorphic near $z = 0$ and $h(0) = 0$, then $|h(z)| \leq C|z|$ near $z = 0$ for some constant $C > 0$. You can, for instance, consider the Taylor expansion of $h$ near $z = 0$ to see this.

Comment: Ah, perfect. $|h(z)|\leq C|z|$, so that upon sending $z \mapsto 1/z$ again, we get $|z^2 f(z) | \leq C$, then just take $C$ sufficiently large I assume?